# Trying to make a super simple clicker game but im getting NaN instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really out of ideas, I've tried everything I can try but can't get this simple thing to work.

**JavaScript**

```
var gurus = document.getElementById('clicks')
var x = gurus.value+1
function guru() { 
  document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = x
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id='clicks'>0</p>
<button onclick='guru()'>Click</button>
```

I made this in a codepen ([link](https://codepen.io/mmccall0813/pen/RqqBpV)).

Comment: try to initialize x first var x =0;

Comment: parseInt() is what you're after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need `innerHTML` not values , since `p` tag does not have values attribute. Secondly you need to get the content of the `p` tag on every click, so put it inside the function.  Use parseInt to convert the string to number

```js
var gurus = document.getElementById('clicks')


function guru() {
  var x = parseInt(gurus.innerHTML, 10) + 1
  document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = x
}
```

```html
<p id='clicks'>0</p>
<button onclick='guru()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a clearner way to achieve the same thing youre trying to do. The code below makes use of `addEventListener` and removes JavaScript function calls from inline HTML (it's not best practice). Make sure to use `parseInt` to convert the `innerHTML` as that was your original issue with the code you posted:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const p = document.querySelector('#clicks');
  const b = document.querySelector('#btn');

  p.append(document.createTextNode("0"));

  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    p.innerHTML = parseInt(p.innerHTML) + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<p id='clicks'></p>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is super simple too! You are treating the `<p>` element as if it was an input field. You need `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`. Then, you need to convert that inner HTML into a number (using `Number()`). Finally, you should move the increment statement:

```
var x = gurus.value + 1
```

into the function, otherwise `x` is just a constant. Here is a working snippet:

```js
  var gurus = document.getElementById('clicks');

function guru() {
  var x = Number(gurus.innerHTML) + 1;
  document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p id='clicks'>0</p>
<button onclick='guru()'>Click</button>
```